# Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to make a menu with asp .net mvc 4.

Calling menu

```
@{Html.RenderAction("LeftMenu", "Navigation",
                      new { currentPoint = ViewData["CurrentCategory"] });}
```

Navigation controller:

```
public ViewResult LeftMenu(string currentPoint) {

        List<NavLink> navLinks = new List<NavLink>();
        navLinks.Add(new CategoryLink(null)
        {
            IsSelected = (currentPoint == null)
        });

        List<string> categories = new List<string>{
            "Bicycles",
            "Details"
        };

        foreach (var category in categories)
            navLinks.Add(new CategoryLink(category){
                IsSelected = (category == currentPoint)
            });

        return View(navLinks);
    }
```

Partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcWebShopApp.Controllers.NavigationController.NavLink>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @foreach (var link in Model)
    {
        <li class = "@(link.IsSelected ? "active": "")">
            <a href="@Url.RouteUrl(link.RouteValues)")>@link.Text</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

But when I run my project I got Exception:

> Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can
>   happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on
>   the stack using too much stack space.

Please help.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: it's to big to show it in comment.

Answer (score 7):

You're actually rendering a full view, not a partial view.
That includes the layout, which renders that view again, creating a stack overflow.

You need to return `PartialView()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I also spent much time on this issue. This fixed my issue.