# ASP.NET MVC - "insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely" within a Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, stack, viewmodel

I'm trying to Add some doctor records through a Partial View. When I'm trying to test the max length of my fields (for instance by putting 31 letters and the limit is 30), I've got the following error:

> insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely

Here's what I'm doing (Model, View and Controller) :

Model :

```
public class DoctorViewModel
{
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Champ requis")]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string DoctorLastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Champ requis")]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
    <div id="addNewMedecin">
        @Html.Action("AddNewMedecin")
    </div>

    <div id="listMedecins">
        @Html.Action("ListMedecins")
    </div>
```

Partial View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewMedecin", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset id="fsMedecins">

        <div class="editor-label">
            Nom :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DoctorLastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.DoctorLastName)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            Prénom :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DoctorName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.DoctorName)
        </div>
        <input id="createNewMedecin" type="submit" name="Enregistrer" value="Enregistrer" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Controller Actions :

```
    public ActionResult Medecins()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddNewMedecin()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewMedecin(DoctorViewModel dvm)
    {
        context = new SchedulingDataClassesDataContext();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DBMedecin newMedecin = new DBMedecin()
            {

                Nom = dvm.DoctorLastName,
                Prenom = dvm.DoctorName
            };

            context.DBMedecins.InsertOnSubmit(newMedecin);
            context.SubmitChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Medecins");
        }

        return View("Medecins");
    }
```

Any idea guys?

Comment: Have you looked at existing questions here on [SO] for this error? In particular, what about [Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358561/insufficient-stack-to-continue-executing-the-program-safely) ? Could it be that you're supposed to return `PartialView` also in that last method there?